# Encoding error in Rails 4 when querying mysql DB

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, encoding, utf-8

I am receiving this error under certain situations when querying my db which is on an aws server (mysql). I have the db configured to utf8 and have the rails app set up to utf-8 as well in the config/application.rb file. Any suggestions?

AwsCourse Load (36.5ms)  SELECT `COURSE`.* FROM `COURSE` WHERE `COURSE`.`id` IN (6, 1, 3, 5, 4, 2)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 128ms (ActiveRecord: 36.5ms)

```
Encoding::UndefinedConversionError ("\xC2" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8):
app/controllers/welcome_controller.rb:22:in `course_search'
```

Comment: `\xc2` is `Â` in ISO 8859-1. Looks like you've loaded some non-UTF8 data into your database and MySQL let you get away with it.

Comment: @muistooshort That makes sense will update after investigation.

Comment: @muistooshort You were right I was able to find the specific entry that was causing the error and the impediment is removed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a non UTF8 character in one of the DB entries. Kudos to @muistoshort for pointing me in the right direction.